# (Sort of) bridge superhub with netgear router WGR614V9

Tags: networking, router, gateway

I've got a virgin super hub (sigh), and a netgear WGR614V9 plugged into eachother. They form two separate networks in the house. The WGR614V9 has a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and the superhub has a subnet mask of 255.255.254.0

When I access the WGR614V9 I can ping and interact with devices on the SuperHub. But not the other way around. For example:

The WGR614V9 has a gateway IP of 192.168.1.1 The superhub has a gateway IP of 192.168.0.1

I can ping the superhub via the WGR614V9 box, but not the other way around.

The reason I ask is that I'm trying to run separate 2GHZ and 5GHZ WIFI networks, and I've also run out of ports on the back of the superhub to run my freenas server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

set both netmasks to 255.255.0.0

Comment: Apparently I can't changet subnet masks on the super hub.... can they both be set to 255.255.254.0? Will that work?

Comment: My TCP/IP skills aren't 100%, but I _think_ that will work.  This is the type of problem you should try experimenting with :)

Comment: Yup, you were pretty much right :) I needed to set both to 255.255.255.0, then move the ethernet cable into a standard ethernet port on the WGR614V9 and then turn off DHCP on that - it all sort of started behaving nicely :)